# How can I force a Worklight Android hybrid app to crash?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I know it sounds strange to WANT an app to crash, but I am testing an application that captures app crash data.  I would like to create a sample hybrid app that crashes on demand.  Typical errors such as divide by zero and null pointer exceptions in the Javascript are handled by the system but the app does not crash.  I also tried causing a crash in a Cordova plug-in in Java code but of course that only crashes the plug-in, not the parent app.

Ideas?

Comment: Sending a BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast crashes the app at my side. Try performing the same?

Comment: have you thought of trowing a RuntimeException, let's say after X invocations?

Comment: For Example, through an uncaught exception: throw new RuntimeException("Crash!");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to crash the thread in which Worklight runs. In that case, you can go to your AppName.java and throw a runtime exception wherever you want to. It could be onCreate or any other of the Android lifecycle events. (This is in src/com.projectName in your Android project).

Answer (score 0):

1. invoke requestFeature() after setting content view
2. try to open activity not declared in androidmanifest.xml
3. do an action requiring specific permission but do not request this permission in androidmanifest.xml